# Is this a valid proof of the reverse triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Here is my proof of the reverse triangle inequality. Note that we are given the fact that $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$

> Suppose a = y, b = x-y, then
>
> $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|\implies|y + x-y| \leq |y| + |x-y|$
>
> $\implies |x| \leq |y| + |x-y|$
>
> $\implies |x| - |y| \leq |x - y|$
>
> Now suppose a = x-y, b = -x, then
>
> $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$ => $|x - y - x| \leq |x-y| + |-x|$
>
> $\implies|-y| \leq |x-y| + |x|$
>
> $\implies|y| - |x| \leq |x - y|$
>
> Thus since $|x - y| \geq |x| - |y|$ and $|x-y| \geq |y| - |x|$, $|x-y| \geq ||x|-|y||$

My issue with this is that my proof of part 2 supposes values of $a$ and $b$ that are different than those in part 1. Is this allowed? If not, how would I go about proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

$a$ and $b$ can take arbitary value.

Remark: After you have proven $$|x|-|y| \leq |x-y|$$

In fact, you can just switch the role of $x$ and $y$, and conclude that

$|y|-|x| \leq |y-x|=|x-y|$ directly.